# Calendar is not Highlighting Accurate Time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been utilizing this calendar and have observed that it is not functioning correctly, as it occasionally highlights incorrect time entries.

For instance, in a sheet titled "Data" containing meeting information, I have identified a row where the duration of time is not accurately highlighted. For example, if the meeting is scheduled from `6:00 PM to 6:30 PM`, the calendar should highlight the specific date from `6:00 PM` to `6:30 PM`. However, it only highlights the cell for `6:00 PM` whic is weired.

I hope someone can help or suggest a better ida to fix this. Thanks

**Data Sheet**
[image]

**Calendar sheet**
[image]

I have attached a file link too to check the workbook
[File Link](https://filebin.net/a22i7bgirs643s7x)

Formula that i have using below formula, I have removed the Meeting Formula it only contains to highlight only the deadlines.

```
=IFERROR(
Control!$D$14&INDEX(tab_calendar_data[Meeting / Deadline],
MATCH(
LARGE(
(tab_calendar_data[Type]=Control!$C$14)*(tab_calendar_data[Start Time]<=$B7)*(tab_calendar_data[End Time]>=$B7)*(tab_calendar_data[Start Date]<=C$6)*(tab_calendar_data[End Date]>=C$6)*
(((WEEKDAY(C$6)<>1)*(WEEKDAY(C$6)<>7)*(tab_calendar_data[Cycle]="daily"))+
(((WEEKDAY(tab_calendar_data[Start Date])=WEEKDAY(C$6))*(tab_calendar_data[Cycle]="weekly"))+
((MOD(C$6-tab_calendar_data[Start Date],14)=0)*(tab_calendar_data[Cycle]="bi-weekly"))+
((MOD(C$6-tab_calendar_data[Start Date],28)=0)*(tab_calendar_data[Cycle]="monthly"))+
((tab_calendar_data[Start Date]=C$6)*(tab_calendar_data[Cycle]="one-time"))))
*tab_calendar_data[ID],1),tab_calendar_data[ID],
0)),"")
```

Comment: I don't think this is wrong: the meeting takes 30 minutes - and that is what one row represents ...

Comment: You are correct. Can you please advise on how I can highlight both cells for a 30-minute duration? As you can see, the other cells highlighted in red also represent a 30-minute time frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, this isn't an answer since it's addressing the question in your comment, rather than the original question...

```
=IFERROR(
Control!$D$14&INDEX(tab_calendar_data[Meeting / Deadline],
MATCH(
LARGE(
(tab_calendar_data[Type]=Control!$C$14)*(ROUND(tab_calendar_data[Start Time],8)<=ROUND($B7,8))*(ROUND(tab_calendar_data[End Time],8)>=ROUND($B7,8))*(tab_calendar_data[Start Date]<=C$6)*(tab_calendar_data[End Date]>=C$6)*
(((WEEKDAY(C$6)<>1)*(WEEKDAY(C$6)<>7)*(tab_calendar_data[Cycle]="daily"))+
(((WEEKDAY(tab_calendar_data[Start Date])=WEEKDAY(C$6))*(tab_calendar_data[Cycle]="weekly"))+
((MOD(C$6-tab_calendar_data[Start Date],14)=0)*(tab_calendar_data[Cycle]="bi-weekly"))+
((MOD(C$6-tab_calendar_data[Start Date],28)=0)*(tab_calendar_data[Cycle]="monthly"))+
((tab_calendar_data[Start Date]=C$6)*(tab_calendar_data[Cycle]="one-time"))))
*tab_calendar_data[ID],1),tab_calendar_data[ID],
0)),"")
```

The roundings are necessary because, in the example of `E30` on the calendar sheet, the `tab_calendar_data[End Time]>=$B30` evaluates to a sequence of `FALSE` values because the latest [End Time], i.e. `0.770833333333333` is never (quite) equal to the value in `B30` of `0.770833333333334`.
If you don't want to change the formula then you could, instead, eliminate the formulae in the `B8:B33` range, e.g. entering the value `0.75` in `B29` will also cause `E30` to turn red (when the date in `F2` is June 1st, 2020).

Comment: Thank you for thoroughly reviewing the formula. Your input is greatly appreciated and your insight is invaluable. It is indeed a correct solution. @Spectral Instance